# Local/host taskbar not displaying when I mouse over bottom of screen in maximized Remote Desktop Connection Window

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, mouse, taskbar

Most questions I see are asking how to view the remote machine's taskbar. I'm looking for the opposite. I wish to view my local/host taskbar while the RDP window is maximized. Local machine is Windows 10. RDP machine is Windows Server 2012 R2.

With the RDP window maximized, I move my mouse to the bottom of the screen and the expectation is the local taskbar should pop up over the remote machine's taskbar. This is not happening. In order to bring up the local taskbar with the RDP window maximized, I must press the Windows button on the keyboard. This stifles my workflow.

With Windows 7 as the local machine, this function worked as intended. Had no issue bringing up the local taskbar with RDP window maximized simply by hovering the mouse to the very bottom of the screen. Seems like something may have changed in Windows 10. There must be some way to bring up the local taskbar on top of a maximized RDP window.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Behavior of Win10 is more appropriate, or the local auto show will interfere remote auto show if any exists. Try non-full screen or workaround the reason you need that workflow.

Comment: I, too, am desperately searching for an answer to this question. Please follow up if you find the answer!